# Is EC integrated encryption scheme used in practice?

Tags: elliptic-curves, ecies

I know ECDSA and ECDH are used a lot but what about the ECIES? Is it used or specified as an option in any protocol?

Comment: Not in the area of CMS based applications (S/Mime, ASx) and not with regulär X.509 based PKIs and card solutions. Strange enough...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, ECIES is used in practice. That's the simplest way (thus arguably the best) to establish a key or/and encipher using Elliptic Curve Cryptography in contexts including unidirectional data transfer, or data-at-rest like backup with encryption under public key.

As an illustration, it is often listed in the *Other algorithms* section of [FIPS-140-validated cryptographic devices](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140val-all.htm); I count like 28 occurrences.

ECIES is in the de-facto standard [SEC 1](http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=56), [IEEE Std 1363a-2004](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1363a-2004.html), and [ANSI X9.63-2011](https://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ANSI%20X9.63-2011%20(R2017)). It is used e.g. in Intelligent Transport Systems as specified by [ETSI TS 103 097](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/103000_103099/103097/01.02.01_60/ts_103097v010201p.pdf). The similar ECIES-KEM is in [ISO/IEC 18033-2:2006](https://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_isoiec18033-2%7Bed1.0%7Den.pdf) following a well-documented [proposal](http://www.shoup.net/papers/iso-2_1.pdf) by Victor Shoup.

Answer (score 6):

Another example is Google's [Android Pay](https://developers.google.com/android-pay/integration/payment-token-cryptography):

> Android Pay uses Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme (ECIES)
>   to secure the payment method token returned in the full Wallet
>   response

Answer (score 5):

It's not exactly as in the standards that [fgrieu cited](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/51204/49826), but [libsodium's sealed box](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/public-key_cryptography/sealed_boxes.html) abstraction is essentially the same idea.